# prevent sudo command when executing a bash script

Tags: bash, sudo

I am aware that I can prevent `sudo` command while I execute script; Suppose I have one test bash script and I don’t want that someone executes this script by issuing the following command:

```
username:~#sudo ./test
```

I implement one of following methods to prevent the above execution, I also implement one `die` method for that.

```
if [[ $UID = 0 ]] ; then
  die "Please dont use sudo command with script"
fi
```

But i am not sure what I'm supposed to implement if root user themselves want to use the script. My above method will prevent root to use that script.

I am ok if root wants to execute script by this manner

```
root:~#./test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could check `$SUDO_USER`

from man page of sudo:

```
SUDO_USER
Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.
```

a little test:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z $SUDO_USER ]] && echo "Not from sudo" || echo "You are from sudo"
```

save it as `t.sh` then we have:

```
kent$  ./t.sh
Not from sudo

kent$  su
Password: 

root# ./t.sh
Not from sudo

kent$  sudo ./t.sh
You are from sudo
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/568627). In essence, there are multiple environment variables set:

```
SUDO_COMMAND
SUDO_USER
SUDO_UID
SUDO_GID
```

As noted in the linked post, they can be faked by setting them by hand. It might help you in your case, though.